# Insert existing element an just created one

Tags: javascript, dom

If I have: `<span>Some Code Here</span>`, can I create a new `div` element and move the `span` element inside just created `div`?

The new element must be in same place where `span` element was before

I'd like to use pure javascript code

Comment: yep, pretty easy to do.. just supply some more code, so we can help you with that :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Wrapping an Element using Pure JavaScript !](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3337587/wrapping-an-element-using-pure-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var wrapper = document.createElement('div');
var selected_span = document.getElementByTagName('span')[0]; //get the first available span element
span_clone = selected_span.cloneNode(true);
selected_span.parentNode.insertBefore(wrapper, selected_span);
selected_span.parentNode.removeChild(selected_span);
wrapper.appendChild(span_clone);
```

What this does is create a new `<div>`, creates copy of the `span`, removes the original `span` and then inserts the copy inside the `div`

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HHTda/1/)

[this](http://jsfiddle.net/HHTda/4/) is the same example within a container

Answer (score 3):

HTML:

```
<span id="the_id">Some code...</span>
```

JS:

```
var the_div = document.getElementById('the_id');
var foobar = document.createElement('div');
foobar.appendChild(the_id);
the_id.parentNode.replaceChild(foobar, the_id);
```

Comment: the div must be in same place where span element was

Comment: Nice, I was doing it the clone/insertBefore/remove way S: +1!

Answer (score 0):

here you go:

http://jsbin.com/uyiluf/3

source:

http://jsbin.com/uyiluf/3/edit#source

Comment: welcome to SO :) Answers containing links to code/examples should also include the linked-to source code.