# CKeditor contenteditable preg_match

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, ckeditor

I am using inline CKeditor, in order to have each paragraph quote treated as a contenteditable div so the toolbar moves with the content, I am using a javascript setInterval to periodically insert the content into a database through ajax.

I'm replacing every `<p>` tag with `<div contenteditable="true"><p>` with PHP:

```
if(preg_match('/<p>/', $post)) {
   $newpost = str_replace("<p>", "<div contenteditable=\"true\"><p class=\"paragraph\">", $post);
}
else {
   $newpost = $post;
}
```

The code works fine when updating with ajax the first time but on a manual refresh it will insert an extra `<div contenteditable="true">`

Example:
On first refresh it enters

```
<div contenteditable="true"><p>
```

On second refresh it enters

```
<div contenteditable="true"><div contenteditable="true"><p>
```

On third refresh it enters

```
<div contenteditable="true"><div contenteditable="true"><div contenteditable="true"><p>
```

This only happens with a manual page refresh not with setInterval.

I'm pretty sure it has something to do with the preg_match I am using because if I insert the code below into the database and refresh the page the content appears exactly as it should.

```
<div contenteditable="true"><p>Lorum Ipsum</p></div>
```

Can anyone show me what I'm doing wrong please?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> I'm replacing every `<p>` tag with `<div contenteditable="true"><p>` with PHP:

Use JavaScript! This is not a task for server-side. Try [jQuery's wrap](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) or do it [the native way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3337587/wrapping-a-dom-element-using-pure-javascript).