# How can I insert existing elements into a dynamically created element using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

**I want to add a main DIV outside the individual many DIVs by CSS, so I can control the whole DIV by an ID.**

```html
<div class="div 1">div 1</div>
<div class="div 2">div 2</div>
<div class="div 3">div 3</div>
<div class="div 4">div 4</div>
<div class="div 5">div 5</div>

I want to like this way:

<div id="myId">
   <div class="div 1">div 1</div>
   <div class="div 2">div 2</div>
   <div class="div 3">div 3</div>
   <div class="div 4">div 4</div>
   <div class="div 5">div 5</div>
</div>
```

But I want to do this by CSS only because the html part is coming from third party, so I can't edit or add anything in the html. But I can edit by CSS.

Thanks in advance, :) taps

Comment: You want to inject markup into your page using CSS?

Comment: To wrap elements you either need access to the `HTML` markup or `Javascript`.

Comment: It's not possible to change HTML structure by CSS.

Comment: You could ask the provider of the HTML code to add what you're after? They may offer alternative suggestions that might help.

Comment: @Jack Zelig, yes exactly.

Comment: @MelanciaUK, yes, i can access Javascript but not HTML. So how i can do this by Javascript?

Comment: [Wrapping a set of DOM elements using JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3337587/wrapping-a-set-of-dom-elements-using-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot inject any markup via CSS.
CSS is a stylesheet language, used to style documents written in HTML

However, you *can* create a new div element, append it to your page, then insert the existing div elements into it using JavaScript.

Here's how:

```
var div = document.createElement('div'),
    divs = document.querySelectorAll('div'),
    len = divs.length,
    i;

// Set any necessary attributes
div.id = "myDiv";

for(i = 0; i < len; i++) {
  div.appendChild(divs[i]);
}

document.body.appendChild(div);
```

This will result in the desired markup:

```
<div id="myDiv">
  <div class="div 1">div 1</div>
  <div class="div 2">div 2</div>
  <div class="div 3">div 3</div>
  <div class="div 4">div 4</div>
  <div class="div 5">div 5</div>
</div>
```

Please note that `document.querySelectorAll('div')` selects any divs on the page. You will need to make this more specific to your case, e.g. `document.querySelectorAll('div.myClass')`