# Wrap <a> around <div> without jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to wrap an `<a>` around a `<div>` without using jQuery since I don't want to embed the jQuery library. Is it possible with pure JavaScript?

The jQuery solution works great and looks like this:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#mydiv").wrap("<a id='myanchor' href='#'></a>");
    });
</script>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Wrapping a set of DOM elements using JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3337587/wrapping-a-set-of-dom-elements-using-javascript)

Comment: jQuery IS javascript so you don't need jQuery at all.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can create a new `link` Element, copy the HTML of the DIV into the link and then insert the link element into the DOM using [`insertBefore`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore)

```js
  function moveToLink(){
    var div = document.getElementById('wrapMe');
    
    var link = document.createElement('a');
    link.innerHTML = div.outerHTML;
    link.setAttribute('href', '#');
    
    div.parentNode.insertBefore(link, div);
    div.remove();
  }
```

```html
<div id="wrapMe">Some content in a div</div>
<input type="button" value="try me" onclick="moveToLink()">
```