# Wrapping HTML in string form with <span>

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I have some HTML represented as a string.

ex:

```
var testHTMLString = "<div class='a'>test content</div>"
```

I want to be able to use regex and split this HTML string by its tags and wrap the broken up tag pieces with `<span class='red'>` and `</span>` in order to highlight pieces of the HTML string

expected result:

```
<span class='red'>"<div class='a'>"</span>test content<span class='red'>"</div>"</span>
```

I can't seem to get the regex correct in my program but in regex testers it seems to work

`testHTMLString.split("/<(\/)?div.*?>/g");` is not splitting my HTML string into the pieces I want --> `"<div class='a'>"` and `"</div>"`

Comment: [You can parse HTML with RegEx if you know what you are going to do](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4234491/1020526)

Comment: All I want to do is wrap a targeted HTML tag with `<span class=red>` to highlight it...

Comment: You can also try to do it with 'split' / 'join' methods, instead of regex

Comment: So why a valid HTML opening tag alone should be wrapped in `span`?

Comment: I also noticed when it can be used. @Biffen

Comment: Then do you think OP knows it? @Biffen

Comment: I am trying to keep the HTML in a string. I want to display it. Not have valid HTML

Comment: I didn't even read question while commenting since that comment was easily against yours. @Biffen

Comment: After rethinking what I need. I think i need `.split()`. Either way, I still need to look in the HTML string?. input --> `"<div class='a'>test content</div>"` output --> `<span class='red'>"<div class='a'>"</span>test content<span class='red'>"</div>"</span>`

Comment: @Biffen made changes to the question thanks for the help!

Comment: @Liondancer what are you trying to accomplish ? Is it only highlighting text or something more ?

Comment: @Tomas Just highlight text. This text happens to LOOK like HTML. Imagine c/p page source from a website

Comment: I'd be happy if you tell me what is wrong with my provided answer.

Comment: OP if you only need wrapping I suggest not using RegExp and using browser's build-in HTML parsing capabilities http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3337587/wrapping-a-set-of-dom-elements-using-javascript

@revo using RegExp for HTML parsing is bad practise and in this use-case can be easily avoided. Look a the link above :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already answered your question. But you forgot to return applied changes:

```
function highlightTag(pageSource, tag) {
    var re = new RegExp("<(\/)?" + tag + ".*?>", "g");
    newPageSource = pageSource.replace(re, "<span class='red'>" + tag + "</span>");
    return newPageSource;
}
```

Also that doesn't completely do what you want. This does:

```
function highlightTag(pageSource, tag) {
    var re = new RegExp("(<\/?" + tag + "[^<>]*>)", "g");
    return pageSource.replace(re, "<span class='red'>\"$1\"</span>");
}
```

Comment: Ahh I see where I went wrong. Thanks. I played around with your modified function and it seems to do what I want. Like I mentioned at first, I actually need `.split()`. I changed it in my function accordingly. Thanks. `split()` will return a list and I can just create some HTML wrapping everything that I need with `<mark>`

Answer (score -3):

Most of the times you should not use RegExp to parse HTML. Wrapping elements can be easily solved using browser's HTML-parsing capabilities see [Wrapping a set of DOM elements using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3337587/wrapping-a-set-of-dom-elements-using-javascript)