# JS - Wrap all child elements of div in a wrapper div

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to wrap all the child elements of a `div`, inside an inner-wrapper `div`.

From this :

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="first-child>
    <div class="second-child>
    <div class="third-child>
 </div>
```

To this :

```
 <div class="parent">
    <div class="inner-wrapper>
        <div class="first-child>
        <div class="second-child>
        <div class="third-child>
    </div>
 </div>
```

I've tried to use [replaceChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/replaceChild) but I'm not sure how it works.

Trying to do this in native js only :)

Comment: There are many question on StackOverflow targeting this topic. Please take the time and look trough those questions and answer. If those do not fully answer your question, then refere to them and explain why they do not answer your question.

Comment: I couldn't find any actually, probably a wrong use of keywords, thanks for the links :)

Comment: [Wrapping a set of DOM elements using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3337587)