# How to wrap a element to new element one created

Tags: javascript

I am trying to wrap a `DOM` element to new element one I create. But not works.

```js
function moveToLink(){
        var button = document.getElementById('button');
        var link = document.createElement('a');
        link.setAttribute('href', '#');
        
        link.appendChild( button); // need wrap
     
      }
      
      moveToLink();
```

```css
a{
  border:2px solid gray;
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" id="button" value="try me" onclick="moveToLink()">
```

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3gwebtrain/t8Lf64p0/11/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wrapping a set of DOM elements using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3337587/wrapping-a-set-of-dom-elements-using-javascript)

Comment: You miss the last step of the duplicate.

Comment: Bear in mind that it is not valid to have an `<input>` inside of an `<a>`.

Comment: There is no existing dom in the html in the above suggestion. I like to `wrap` the exisint element to dynamic one

Comment: Add `document.body.appendChild(link);`

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol - as a sample work I do this.

Comment: Just before `link.appendChild..` use `button.parentNode.insertBefore(link,button)` to put the new element in the place of the old element.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol - I don't want to append in Before. If there might be other children will be exist. I just want to replace with same `DOM` Level where the original placed before

Comment: That's exactly what `button.parentNode.insertBefore(link,button)` does. It inserts the new element immediately before the button. That is to say, in the exact same place once the button has been moved into the new element.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol - can you have a look here : http://jsfiddle.net/3gwebtrain/t8Lf64p0/45/ - recreate a fiddle for me

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/t8Lf64p0/71/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't append link itself to body.

Edit: Changed code to replace element instead of append, it wasn't what you wanted. And it doesn't work with link because it can't wrap input. check [here](http://jsfiddle.net/t8Lf64p0/67/)

```
function moveToLink(){
    var button = document.getElementById('button');
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    document.getElementsByClassName('parent')[0].replaceChild(div, button);
    div.appendChild( button);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you have to append the "link" element to a part of the document.
After that clicking on that link appends the button to "link".

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script> 
      function moveToLink(){
        var button = document.getElementById('button');
        var link = document.createElement('a');
        link.setAttribute('href', '#');
        document.body.appendChild(link);
        link.appendChild( button);
      }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="button" id="button" value="try me" onclick="moveToLink()" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: add the js part of the code in a script tag like my code:              

<script> 
      function moveToLink(){
        var button = document.getElementById('button');
        var link = document.createElement('a');
        link.setAttribute('href', '#');
        document.body.appendChild(link);
        link.appendChild( button);
      }
    </script>

Comment: upvoted just because you are new, using SO with very low rep is very frustrating. The code you gave creates invalid html (<input> inside <a> tag), but that's what OP wanted, not your fault.